# Method to reorganize messed mm/dd/yy and dd/mm/yy date

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
structure(list(dateofinterview = structure(c("5/29/2018", "9/3/2018", 
"6/14/2018", "30/11/2017", "20/04/2018", "1/12/2018", "25/01/2018", 
"16/03/2018", "13/03/2018", "5/17/2018", "17/08/2018", "7/3/2018", 
"29/05/2018", "2/8/2018", "1/11/2018", "8/8/2018", "2/27/2018", 
"22/02/2018", "11/12/2017", "19/07/2018", "14/08/2018", "29/11/2017", 
"29/01/2018", "12/5/2017", "20/08/2018", "29/01/2018", "5/12/2017", 
"8/20/2018", "24-05-2018", "1/11/2018", "24/07/2018", "31/05/2018", 
"7/17/2018", "30/11/2017", "4/12/2017", "24-05-2018", "23-05-2018", 
"25-05-2018", "26/02/2018", "12/5/2017", "16/08/2018", "10/1/2018", 
"10/8/2018", "12/1/2018", "8/20/2018", "5/7/2018", "7/5/2018", 
"16/08/2018", "1/17/2018", "4/18/2018", "3/13/2018", "8/5/2018", 
"19/02/2018", "5/25/2018", "12/1/2018", "31/05/2018", "7/5/2018", 
"16/05/2017", "15/12/2017", "30/11/207", "9/5/2018", "8/20/2018", 
"11/8/2018", "15/12/2017", "6/14/2018", "7/12/2018", "24-05-2018", 
"22/02/2018", "12/5/2017", "5/4/2018", "22/02/2018", "15/02/2018", 
"5/6/2018", "7/13/2018", "5/24/2018", "2/21/2018", "20/08.2018", 
"1/12/2018", "21/02/2018", "12/1/2018", "20-06-2018", "3/26/2018", 
"1/11/2018", "7/17/2018", "7/12/2018", "28/5/2018", "15/01/2018", 
"28/07/2018", "31/01/2018", "2/23/2018", "8/5/2018", "1/11/2018", 
"8/5/2018", "7/5/2018", "24-05-2018", "15/12/2017", "3/8/2018", 
"10/5/2018", "24-05-2018", "15/01/2018"), format.stata = "%10s"), 
    a = c(5, 9, 6, 30, 20, 1, 25, 16, 13, 5, 17, 7, 29, 2, 1, 
    8, 2, 22, 11, 19, 14, 29, 29, 12, 20, 29, 5, 8, 24, 1, 24, 
    31, 7, 30, 4, 24, 23, 25, 26, 12, 16, 10, 10, 12, 8, 5, 7, 
    16, 1, 4, 3, 8, 19, 5, 12, 31, 7, 16, 15, 30, 9, 8, 11, 15, 
    6, 7, 24, 22, 12, 5, 22, 15, 5, 7, 5, 2, 20, 1, 21, 12, 20, 
    3, 1, 7, 7, 28, 15, 28, 31, 2, 8, 1, 8, 7, 24, 15, 3, 10, 
    24, 15), b = c(29, 3, 14, 11, 4, 12, 1, 3, 3, 17, 8, 3, 5, 
    8, 11, 8, 27, 2, 12, 7, 8, 11, 1, 5, 8, 1, 12, 20, 5, 11, 
    7, 5, 17, 11, 12, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 8, 1, 8, 1, 20, 7, 5, 8, 
    17, 18, 13, 5, 2, 25, 1, 5, 5, 5, 12, 11, 5, 20, 8, 12, 14, 
    12, 5, 2, 5, 4, 2, 2, 6, 13, 24, 21, 8, 12, 2, 1, 6, 26, 
    11, 17, 12, 5, 1, 7, 1, 23, 5, 11, 5, 5, 5, 12, 8, 5, 5, 
    1), year = c("2018", "2018", "2018", "2017", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2017", "2018", "2018", "2017", 
    "2018", "2017", "2018", "2018", "2017", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2017", "2017", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2017", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2017", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2017", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2017", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```

When the data collector input the date, they messed the format of date, the original input is the col of "dateofinterview", from there, there are either mm/dd/yy format or dd/mm/yy format. I need to find out which are mm/dd/yy format, which are dd/mm/format, and convert them to a unified format: mm/dd/yy in new col if it is possible.

So my thought is like: first, I separate the dates into "a", "b" and "year". And try to compare a and b's value. like using 12 as threshold value to tell whether it is month or day. But it does not work very well. For those both a and b are less then 12, it is less likely to tell which is month and which is day without further information, but is there any way to at least to convert rest of them?

Thanks a lot~~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `parse_date` to parse most of the formats and then convert back to a particular format with `format`

```
library(parsedate)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(dateofinterview2 = format(parse_date(dateofinterview), 
         "%m/%d/%y"))
```

-output

```
> df1$dateofinterview
  [1] "5/29/2018"  "9/3/2018"   "6/14/2018"  "30/11/2017" "20/04/2018" "1/12/2018"  "25/01/2018" "16/03/2018" "13/03/2018" "5/17/2018" 
 [11] "17/08/2018" "7/3/2018"   "29/05/2018" "2/8/2018"   "1/11/2018"  "8/8/2018"   "2/27/2018"  "22/02/2018" "11/12/2017" "19/07/2018"
 [21] "14/08/2018" "29/11/2017" "29/01/2018" "12/5/2017"  "20/08/2018" "29/01/2018" "5/12/2017"  "8/20/2018"  "24-05-2018" "1/11/2018" 
 [31] "24/07/2018" "31/05/2018" "7/17/2018"  "30/11/2017" "4/12/2017"  "24-05-2018" "23-05-2018" "25-05-2018" "26/02/2018" "12/5/2017" 
 [41] "16/08/2018" "10/1/2018"  "10/8/2018"  "12/1/2018"  "8/20/2018"  "5/7/2018"   "7/5/2018"   "16/08/2018" "1/17/2018"  "4/18/2018" 
 [51] "3/13/2018"  "8/5/2018"   "19/02/2018" "5/25/2018"  "12/1/2018"  "31/05/2018" "7/5/2018"   "16/05/2017" "15/12/2017" "30/11/207" 
 [61] "9/5/2018"   "8/20/2018"  "11/8/2018"  "15/12/2017" "6/14/2018"  "7/12/2018"  "24-05-2018" "22/02/2018" "12/5/2017"  "5/4/2018"  
 [71] "22/02/2018" "15/02/2018" "5/6/2018"   "7/13/2018"  "5/24/2018"  "2/21/2018"  "20/08.2018" "1/12/2018"  "21/02/2018" "12/1/2018" 
 [81] "20-06-2018" "3/26/2018"  "1/11/2018"  "7/17/2018"  "7/12/2018"  "28/5/2018"  "15/01/2018" "28/07/2018" "31/01/2018" "2/23/2018" 
 [91] "8/5/2018"   "1/11/2018"  "8/5/2018"   "7/5/2018"   "24-05-2018" "15/12/2017" "3/8/2018"   "10/5/2018"  "24-05-2018" "15/01/2018"
attr(,"format.stata")
[1] "%10s"
> df1$dateofinterview2
  [1] "05/29/18" "09/03/18" "06/14/18" "11/30/17" "04/20/18" "01/12/18" "01/25/18" "03/16/18" "03/13/18" "05/17/18" "08/17/18" "07/03/18"
 [13] "05/29/18" "02/08/18" "01/11/18" "08/08/18" "02/27/18" "02/22/18" "11/12/17" "07/19/18" "08/14/18" "11/29/17" "01/29/18" "12/05/17"
 [25] "08/20/18" "01/29/18" "05/12/17" "08/20/18" "05/24/18" "01/11/18" "07/24/18" "05/31/18" "07/17/18" "11/30/17" "04/12/17" "05/24/18"
 [37] "05/23/18" "05/25/18" "02/26/18" "12/05/17" "08/16/18" "10/01/18" "10/08/18" "12/01/18" "08/20/18" "05/07/18" "07/05/18" "08/16/18"
 [49] "01/17/18" "04/18/18" "03/13/18" "08/05/18" "02/19/18" "05/25/18" "12/01/18" "05/31/18" "07/05/18" "05/16/17" "12/15/17" "11/30/22"
 [61] "09/05/18" "08/20/18" "11/08/18" "12/15/17" "06/14/18" "07/12/18" "05/24/18" "02/22/18" "12/05/17" "05/04/18" "02/22/18" "02/15/18"
 [73] "05/06/18" "07/13/18" "05/24/18" "02/21/18" "08/20/18" "01/12/18" "02/21/18" "12/01/18" "06/20/18" "03/26/18" "01/11/18" "07/17/18"
 [85] "07/12/18" "05/28/18" "01/15/18" "07/28/18" "01/31/18" "02/23/18" "08/05/18" "01/11/18" "08/05/18" "07/05/18" "05/24/18" "12/15/17"
 [97] "03/08/18" "10/05/18" "05/24/18" "01/15/18"
```

NOTE: There could be some instances which can go wrong especially when there is a two digit year or a day value less than 12

Comment: Thanks a lot~~@akrun, may I ask that this "parsedate" can automatically tell the difference between dd/mm/yy and mm/dd/yy, and then convert them to the unified format like mm/dd/yy (Except for some special values as you mentioned in answer). Do i understand right?

Comment: @Rstudyer it can automatically detect a lot of those formats.  In general, it is better to have 4 digit year instead of 2 digit as this can create confusion with 19 and 20..